# How to connect to hidden service from node.js using socks4a?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tor, socks

The TOR [documentation](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#AccessHiddenServices) says that SOCKS4a is required to connect to a hidden service. There is a [node library](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-socks-proxy-agent) which implements SOCKS4a.

Assuming one knows the `.onion` address of a hidden service, how should one connect to this hidden service with https to fetch a webpage online from a `node.js` application? A code example would be welcome.

To be more precise, I have installed the Tor cartridge for Openshift, but connecting to it and using it is unclear to me. I have created a related question on [Tor stack exchange](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6940/can-i-fetch-a-webpage-through-a-hidden-service).

Comment: Have you looked at the various TOR-related modules in the NPM repository? [`torfetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/torfetch) seems to be able to do what you want, for instance.

Comment: I did. The module you mention fetches pages on the TOR network itself, not general Internet pages through the TOR network.

Answer (score 0):

Usually TOR hidden services do not use HTTPS because TOR already provides strong encryption around the data packets that are routed thru the network. But some services do use it. I recently had the need to communicate with a web API that was behind a TOR hidden service. Here's what I did to make it work.

Install TOR. On debian/Ubuntu systems:

```sh
sudo apt-get install tor
```

For other systems check [the official website](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/installguide.html.en) for a matching installation guide.

Use the following nodejs script to fetch a web page from a TOR hidden service. By default it will fetch DuckDuckGo's home age which is served by their v3 onion address.

```js
const url = require('url');
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const SocksProxyAgent = require('socks-proxy-agent');

// Use the SOCKS_PROXY env var if using a custom bind address or port for your TOR proxy:
const proxy = process.env.SOCKS_PROXY || 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050';
console.log('Using proxy server %j', proxy);
// The default HTTP endpoint here is DuckDuckGo's v3 onion address:
const endpoint = process.argv[2] || 'https://duckduckgogg42xjoc72x3sjasowoarfbgcmvfimaftt6twagswzczad.onion';
console.log('Attempting to GET %j', endpoint);
// Prepare options for the http/s module by parsing the endpoint URL:
let options = url.parse(endpoint);
const agent = new SocksProxyAgent(proxy);
// Here we pass the socks proxy agent to the http/s module:
options.agent = agent;
// Depending on the endpoint's protocol, we use http or https module:
const httpOrHttps = options.protocol === 'https:' ? https : http;
// Make an HTTP GET request:
httpOrHttps.get(options, res => {
    // Print headers on response:
    console.log('Response received', res.headers);
    // Pipe response body to output stream:
    res.pipe(process.stdout);
});
```

- Save the above script to a file named `tor-http-fetch.js`
- Install the `socks-proxy-agent` npm module: `npm install socks-proxy-agent`
- Run the script: `node tor-http-fetch.js`
- To fetch your own onion service: `node ./tor-http-fetch.js "http://your-tor-hidden-service.onion"`

The above script will work with both http or https URLs.

For further details you can check [here](https://degreesofzero.com/article/fetch-web-page-from-tor-hidden-service-with-nodejs.html)

Good luck!